# convert simple concatenated json to shell variables

Tags: json, bash, jq

Some simple JSON arrives and looks like this. I need to convert it to shell variables, the keys should be uppercase, and also "-" should be converted "_", and finally all key names should be put in shell list to generate the output which you can see below. I managed to do this with a complicated pipe of jq queries, I am wondering if there is a more simple way to do this I jq? Note that the __INDEX0,__INDEX1,... variables in the final output would not be required.

**JSON INPUT (input.json)**

```
{
  "msg-version": "1.0",
  "msg-type":  "app-config",
  "content": "aaa"
}
{
  "msg-version": "1.0",
  "msg-type":  "app-config",
  "content": "bbb"
}
{
  "msg-version": "1.0",
  "msg-type":  "app-config",
  "content": "ddd",
  "breakit": { "a":"b"}
}
```

**SHELL OUTPUT**

```
__INDEX0='0'
MSG_VERSION0='1.0'
MSG_TYPE0='app-config'
CONTENT0='aaa'
__INDEX_NAMES0='CONTENT MSG_TYPE MSG_VERSION'
__INDEX1='1'
MSG_VERSION1='1.0'
MSG_TYPE1='app-config'
CONTENT1='bbb'
__INDEX_NAMES1='CONTENT MSG_TYPE MSG_VERSION'
__INDEX2='2'
MSG_VERSION2='1.0'
MSG_TYPE2='app-config'
CONTENT2='ddd'
BREAKIT2='{"a":"b"}'
__INDEX_NAMES2='BREAKIT CONTENT MSG_TYPE MSG_VERSION'
```

**bash jq quer(ies)**

```
cat input.json|\
jq  'keys as $keys|. + {"__index_names": ($keys|join(" ")|split("-")|join("_")|ascii_upcase)}'|\
jq --slurp 'keys[] as $_k|{ __index: $_k|tostring}*  .[$_k]  '|\
jq -r '.__index as $i|to_entries| .[]| { key: ((.key + $i)|split("-")|join("_")|ascii_upcase), value: (.value) }|.key + "='"'"'" + (.value|tostring) + "'"'"'"')
```

Comment: That input is not JSON! It can be treated like multiple JSON files pasted together, but that's an important difference.

Comment: @UlrickEckhardt - You're right but jq handles JSON streams without fuss. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_streaming#Concatenated_JSON

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt changed the topic to reflect your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the jq command-line options -n and -r, the following produces the output as required (that is, without the superfluous __INDEX keys):

```
def q: if type=="string" then @sh else tojson|@sh end;

foreach inputs as $in (-1;.+1;
  . as $n
  | $in
  | to_entries[]
  | "\(.key|gsub("-";"_")|ascii_upcase + ($n|tostring) )=\(.value|q)"
  )
```

The tricky bit here, of course, is adding the integer suffixes to the key names.

Comment: what a simple solution, thank you very much!